# hibernate update in relation table

Tags: hibernate

I have table structure like:

```
    PRD_CATEGORY_MASTER
    CATEGORY_GUID                       DECIMAL(19,0)
    CATEGORY_PARENT_GUID        DECIMAL(19,0)
    DISPLAY_SEQUENCE                  BIGINT


   PRD_PRODUCT
   GUID
   DISCONTINUED
   NEWIMPORT
   EISIDENTIFIER
   STOCKED
   .....
```

and

```
   PRD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY
   CATEGORY_GUID  DECIMAL(19,0)
   PRODUCT_GUID      DECIMAL(19,0)
   DISPLAY_SEQENCE     BIGINT
```

I have created 2 hbm files for product and categorymaster. The update works good and updates all 3 tables.

The column Display_sequence was added to the table `PRD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY` later, and I do not have created hbm for it and I need to update this column in the table.

Do I need an hbm file for `PRD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY`  as well. ? what are my options for this?
How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the join table contains something other than the foreign keys to the joined tables, you need to map this table as an entity as well.

Comment: This was helpful to get started. I also implemented it. but facing different issue.  The row in the join table is updated then deleted and inserted. Is there any example on Hibernate – Many-to-Many example – join table + extra column using hibernate mapping file? What are the spcific steps I should be following for this. Thanks

Comment: Once the join table AB  between A and B is mapped as an entity, you don't have a many-to-many anymore between A and B: You have a OneToMany between A and AB, and a OneToMany between B and AB.